# android-library with specific Product Flavors dependency

Tags: java, android, build-process, gradle

I'm looking for something like

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    flavor1Compile files('utility.aar')
}
```

Everything fails with:

> Could not find method flavor1Compile() for arguments [file collection] on root project 'SampleProject'.

Comment: visit this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860659/multi-flavor-app-based-on-multi-flavor-library-in-android-gradle/24910671#24910671

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Libraries don't support flavors.

Note that this wouldn't work in a app project because you haven't defined the flavor first. You'd need to do

```
android {
    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {}
    }
}

dependencies {
    flavor1Compile ...
}
```

it wouldn't work in the other order as declaring the product flavor is what create its associated dependency configuration.

Comment: I want to use the dependency as project in studio, but as *.aar on the build server. How can i manage this?

Comment: This is not supported at the moment. This is a well known issue in Gradle itself and it will come at some point.

Comment: @XavierDucrohet Please support android library ndk prebuild

Comment: Any word on when the libraries will be supporting flavors?

Comment: They Just did: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating_to_09

Comment: What we did in 0.9 is not all the work we need to do for full flavor support in libraries. Make sure to read the release notes and updated documentation for current limitations.

Comment: Starting from 0.9 when specifying productFlavors for one of android-library, then processReleaseRsources task fails – doesn't see custom attrs from other libs my project depends on..

Comment: I can't get *android-library* flavors to work at all! Do resources not migrate automatically? I keep getting an error `No resource found that matches the name (at 'theme' with value '@style/MyStyle').`

Answer (score -1):

```
flavor1Implementation files('libs/user/xxx.aar')
```

You can use aar files like this in flavors.