# How can I add flavors in a module with Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have a suite of projects that use the same module, which contains nearly all the actual code. The project is setup like:

```
project/
  - app/
    - build.gradle
  - libraries/
    - module/
      - build.gradle
  - build.gradle
  - settings.gradle
```

The dependencies are all setup correctly, and I can build and run apps great, however I can only add flavors to the project, which is not the ideal solution. *settings.gradle* contains the following:

```
include ':app', ':libraries:module'
```

In the app directory's *build.gradle* file, I added the following block:

```
productFlavors {
    alpha
    production
}
```

Using gradle 0.11, this syncs and creates *assembleAlphaDebug*, *assembleAlphaRelease*, *assembleProductionDebug*, *assembleProductionRelease* tasks. When I attempt to do this in the module instead, I get the error:

> No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/MyCustomTheme')

in the built `app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`. For some reason, the module is not being built, so the custom theme is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As per my understanding even app is a module same as you "module" and putting flavors in any of module will work. What error are you getting while compiling the code.

Comment: @pyus13 Looking further, the error seems to be an issue with not finding a resource for the given flavor. I have a custom theme set in the app's manifest, but I get `No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/MyCustomTheme')`.

Comment: is your module is a library project. Means it has "android-library" or "android" as plugin ?

Comment: @pyus13 it uses the *android-library* plugin.

Comment: As commented by Android Studio team lead here libraries doesn't support flavors . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107908/android-library-with-specific-product-flavors-dependency

Comment: @pyus13 I saw that, but I think it's outdated. This indicates that it should be supported: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating_to_09

Comment: Check this if this could help you https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/iUdV2xVCc38

Comment: What errors are you seeing?

Comment: @ScottBarta I get the error `No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/MyCustomTheme')` when I build the *app*.

Comment: This is sort of a different problem. I think it might help if you recast your question and include more information on how you're setting this theme up and what the dependencies are between main app and library. Your problem doesn't really seem to be with setting a library flavor up, unless that theme resource lives in only one flavor in the library, which isn't clear yet.

Comment: **For more detailed Q/A see:** [Multi Flavor App based on multi Flavor Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860659/multi-flavor-app-based-on-multi-flavor-library-in-android-gradle)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

In the library module's build.gradle, you need a couple extra lines to tell it to export the flavors and which build variant to use by default if not specified when being included from another module:

```
android {
    defaultPublishConfig "productionRelease"
    publishNonDefault true

    productFlavors {
        alpha {
        }
        production {
        }
    }
}
```

That `publishNonDefault` bit is only necessary if someone would want to depend on something other than the `productionRelease` variant. Presumably this is the case if you set up multi-flavors in your library in the first place.

Now if you add a dependency from another module via this in its build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':module')
}
```

it will depend on the `productionRelease` variant by default. If you'd like to depend on a non-default variant:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(path: ':module', configuration:'alphaDebug')
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to depend on flavor only and not on build type as well?

Comment: I assume you meant `compile project(`

Comment: This post helped so much. I've burned a ton of time on this so far.

One thing I've noticed now, is that the build mode specified in defaultPublishConfig is the only thing that can be built now from android studio. Is anyone else experiencing this?

Answer (score 3):

1. First add below gradle code snippet to your app/build.gradle

```
flavorDimensions "env"
productFlavors {
    dev {
        dimension "env"
    }
    pre {
        dimension "env"
    }
    prod {
        dimension "env"
    }
}
```

2. Second, add below gradle code snippet to your module/build.gradle

```
flavorDimensions "env"
productFlavors {
    register("dev")
    register("pre")
    register("prod")
}
```

I have posted an ansower in this
[Use different library module for each android flavor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56372539/use-different-library-module-for-each-android-flavor/71122466#71122466)

Comment: For details see: stackoverflow.com/[**Multi Flavor App with multi Flavor Library?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24860659/8740349)

Comment: Can you explain exactly what 'register' does here? Is this just the same as 'dev { }' in a more concise way, without having to add {'dimension "env" } to each one?