# Use different library module for each android flavor

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-flavors

I want to use a different library module for each flavor.

For example:

- free flavor -> I need to use the free library module
- paid flavor -> I need to use the paid library module

My flavors

```
productFlavors {
    free{
     ....... 
     }
    paid{
     ....... 
     }
   }
```

What I tried

```
freeImplementation  project(path:':freeLib', configuration: 'free')//for free

paidImplementation  project(path:':paidLib', configuration: 'paid')//for paid
```

**But I got compile error not able to use this**

Note: It's not a duplicate question. I already tried some StackOverflow questions. It's outdated (they are using compile)

Reference - [Multi flavor app based on multi flavor library in Android Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860659/multi-flavor-app-based-on-multi-flavor-library-in-android-gradle)

**Solution** (from Gabriele Mariotti comments)

```
 freeImplementation project(path:':freeLib')
 paidImplementation project(path:':paidLib')
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you have a library with multiple product flavors, in your `lib/build.gradle` you can define:

```
android {
    ...
    //flavorDimensions is mandatory with flavors.
    flavorDimensions "xxx"
    productFlavors {
        free{
            dimension "xxx"
        }
        paid{
            dimension "xxx"
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

In your `app/build.gradle` define:

```
android {
    ...

    flavorDimensions "xxx"
    productFlavors {
        free{
            dimension "xxx"

            // App and library's flavor have the same name.
            // MatchingFallbacks can be omitted
            matchingFallbacks = ["free"]
        }
        paid{
            dimension "xxx"

            matchingFallbacks = ["paid"]
        }
    }
    ...
}
dependencies {
    implementation project(':mylib')
}
```

Instead, if you have separate libraries you can simply use in your `app/build.gradle` something like:

```
dependencies {
    freeImplementation project(':freeLib')
    paidImplementation project(':paidLib')
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer.. but I want to use separate library for each flavor. Its possible?

Comment: In this case, if your libraries have product flavors the configuration is the same. Otherwise just use freeImplementation project(':mylib1') and paidImplementation

Comment: yes working for me.. thanks for reply.. 

 freeImplementation project(path:':freeLib')
 paidImplementation project(path:':paidLib')

Comment: Just added my last comment to the answer to support both scenarios.

Comment: matchingFallbacks saved my day. I could have easily spent a whole day figuring that part out for myself.

Comment: This is best answer from all, this allows me to set same flavour for app and library. I don't need to reselect the same from build flavour. Thanks for answer. :)

Answer (score 5):

1. First add below gradle code snippet to your `app/build.gradle`

   ```
   flavorDimensions "env"
   productFlavors {
       dev {
           dimension "env"
       }
       pre {
           dimension "env"
       }
       prod {
           dimension "env"
       }
   }
   ```
2. Second, add below gradle code snippet to your `module/build.gradle`

   ```
   flavorDimensions "env"
   productFlavors {
       register("dev")
       register("pre")
       register("prod")
   }
   ```
3. Sync your project, and then you can find productFlavors were configured success,like below picture
   [image]